# Construction of $E/\mathcal{R}$ : why we need the axiom of choice to find $\overline{x}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

I was thinking about quotient space,

> I have an equivalence relation and we want to construct $E/\mathcal{R}$, the space quotient, the way I know is to choose in any equivalence class an element denoted $\overline{x}$. So that $E/\mathcal{R}$ is the set of $\overline{x}$ for $x\in E$.

And today I learnt that the existence of this element is provided by the axiom of choice, it's the first time I hear about this axiom.

**Question and remark:** Why the existence of such an element it's non trivial a priori? I don't 'see' why choosing $\overline{x}$ can be difficult. 
So my question is not to understand the axiom of choice but why we need such an axiom here.

Comment: The quotient space is usually defined to be set of equivalence classes, not their representatives. No choice is needed this way.

Comment: @lisyarus it's a second way to defined it yes, but my question is not really about choice, please read my question carrefully :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in choosing one particular $\overline x$. To "choose" means to prove it exists, and equivalence classes are non-empty, so such an $\overline x$ definitely exists.

The problem is in choosing one *for every equivalence class simultaneously*, that is, to define a function $f:E/\mathcal{R}\rightarrow E$ such that $f([x])=\overline x \Rightarrow \overline x \in [x]$. This is exactly the axiom of choice applied to the set of equivalence classes.

Comment: @JeSuis glad to be of service!